# C++ program to calculate the factorial of even numbers between 5 and 15

Tags: c++, loops, break, factorial

When I run the program for an even number less than 5, It prints out the error message but it also gives me the factorial. I don't want the factorial. Here's the code, how do I correct it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, factorial = 1;

    cout << "Enter an even number between 5 & 15 to find it's factorial: ";
    cin >> number;

    if(number % 2 == 0) {
        while(number < 5) {
            cout << "Error! Enter an even number greater than five: ";
            break;
        }

        while(number > 15) {
            cout << "Error! Enter an even number less than fifteen: ";
            break;
        }

        for(int a = 1; a <= number; a++) {
            factorial = factorial * a;
        }

        cout << "factorial of " << number << " is " << factorial;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error!Enter an even number between 5 & 15 to find it's "
                "factorial: ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `break` does? What do you think `return` does?

Comment: break ,well I suppose it stops the program from continuing to execute after (in my case) printing, If I remove break and run the program the output continues printing the same message over and over. As, for return my understanding is that it's an exit code , to tell if the program execution is successful.

Comment: @Baibulu Your answer to the question of KarlKnechtel is wrong. I was about to type the correct answer, but actually you should really read about those in some tutorial. Also, note that you haven't addressed him in your answer, thus he won't get a notice that you replied. I addressed you in this very comment so you see how it is done (but since you are wrote the post, you'll see it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows some corrections to be in your code and provide a working piece of code.

Corrections:

1. Not a very good idea to write everything in the main function. Try to follow SOLID principles where S stands for single responsibility. Which tells that functions must be small and do exactly one thing. And in your code, you have defined a very big function which does a lot of things.
2. Avoid nested loops. In your example, you have an if , inside which you have while, while and inside while you have for. This looks messy and is not readable.
   Try to be clear in your expression of code, such that when a person reads they understand the flow of data.
3. Break is something that comes out of a while loop, but it does not mean it will exit the function. So in your example,

   while(number<5){
   std::cout<<"Error! Enter an even number greater than five: ";
   break;
   }

After it comes out of this loop, it will go to the next line which is another while loop and then goes on to calculate the function.

4. Try to use uniform initialization. Instead of int i = 0 use int i{0}. You can read more about uniform initialization on google.
5. Try not to use "using namespace std or anything else". Very bad practice.

Working piece of code:

```
bool check_value(int number){
int range = (number < 5 || number > 15) ? false : true;
int even = (number % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
if(range & even){
    return true;
}
else{
    std::cout << "Error! Please input even number between 5 & 15\n";
    return false;
}}

int main(){   
int number,factorial=1;
std::cout<<"Enter an even number between 5 & 15 to find it's factorial: \n";
    std::cin >> number;
    
if(check_value(number)){
for (size_t a{1}; a <= number; a++){
        factorial = factorial*a;
    }
    std::cout<<"factorial of " << number <<" is " << factorial << "\n";
}            
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Note that you need a `long long int` for factorial

Comment: Hmm, yes in general case it would be a good idea. But the max result this program would calculate is factorial of 14 which is 1278945280, and that is in the range of int. But yes, I would definitely go with long long int in normal factorial program.

Comment: `14! = 8.7e10`, greater than `2^31-1 = 2.14e-9`

Comment: Oops ! yes you are right! my factorial calculation was wrong :D long long int it is.

Answer (score 1):

As Karl pointed out in the comments, the `break` statement will break out of exactly one loop, in this case a `while` loop, and the code outside of the loop will continue to execute.

Also, as Damien pointed out, you need to use a `long long int` to compute the factorial since the result can exceed the max size of the `int` datatype.

You could also reformulate your code to make it more readable, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

/* Checks if number is valid and can throw error msg */
bool isValidNumber(int num) {
    if(num % 2 != 0 || num < 5 || num > 15) {
        std::cout << "Error! The number entered is not valid." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* Calculates factorial and prints its value */
void calculateFactorial(int num) {
    long long int factorial = 1;

    for(int a = 1; a <= num; a++) {
        factorial = factorial * a;
    }

    std::cout << "factorial of " << num << " is " << factorial << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    bool isValid;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter an even number between 5 & 15 to find it's factorial: ";
        std::cin >> number;

        isValid = isValidNumber(number);

        if(isValid) {
            calculateFactorial(number);
        }
    } while(!isValid);

   return 0;
}
```

**Note:** Using `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice because of the possibility of method collisions between a method or methods in the `std` namespace and methods of some other nanmespace you might create down the road.